# AngularJs: ng-model is not getting set with typehead

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying the access the input field value using `ng-model searchQuery`but it's not getting set. After removing `typehead` and `typeahead-editable` it works fine.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group" class="pull-right" style="margin: 10px">
                        <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Get quote..." ng-model="searchQuery"
                             ng-controller="TypeaheadController"
                             typeahead="script as script.symbol for script in getSymbols($viewValue)"
                             typeahead-editable="false"> 
                            Value - {{searchQuery}}
                            <span
                            class="input-group-btn"> <a class="btn btn-default"
                            type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#search-popup"> 
                            <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
                                </span>
                              </a> 
                              <a class="btn btn-default" type="button"
                            ng-href="#/show-details/{{searchQuery}}"> <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Not getting any errors in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `ng-controller="TypeaheadController"` statement to parent div, it will work fine.